# Jenkins script tar: write error

Tags: linux, node.js, jenkins, tar

We run a script in Jenkins that perform npm install and webpack production build,
After that it creates a tar and try to copy it to a remote server.

script example:

```
  npm install
  npm run build
  cd build
  sudo tar -zcvf ../${TGZ_FILE} .
```

But we get that error:

```
tar: write error
```

Any idea why it happens?

Answer (score 13):

I've been encountering the same problem two weeks ago. While hitting tar from the command line, everything seemed working fine.

I had a strange feeling, that Jenkins couldn't handle that much output (which of course makes no sense) and **removed the verbose flag**. That somehow solved our issues.

Try running less verbose (without -v):

```
npm install
npm run build
cd build
sudo tar -zcf ../${TGZ_FILE} .
```

To be honest, I have no idea yet, what caused these issues - however, I hope it solves your problem, too.

Notice: Think about avoiding `sudo`, since it's considered bad practice to use it in shell scripts.

Comment: I could not believe that would fix it. But it did, so it's still true for Jenkins 2.121.1. Really odd and creates this kind of 'No wayyyyy' moment :)

Comment: removing -v just fixed the same issue that I had. many thanks, I couldn't guess such fix!

Comment: The first result for a google search of simply "tar: write error" brought me to this answer, which fixed this oddly specific issue in Jenkins.

Comment: Omitting the verbose option (`-v`) seems to be a general solution. Got here by getting the error when extracting the Android Studio `tar.gz`, and simply using `-zxf` indeed solved it.

Comment: Same issue when running command from a child_process in Node app. Removing the verbose flag also fixed the tar: write error.